# How to factorise this expression $ x^2-y^2-x+y$

Tags: factoring

This part can be factorised as  $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$, How would the rest of the expression be factorised ?

:)

Comment: Oops. I wanted to post the factorisation of x^2 - y^2 as a hint, because once that is factored, the rest is trivial. Or so I thought. Hint 2: There is another x - y in the expression.

Comment: The trivial observation is here that $-x+y$ is $(-1)(x-y)$ ( and $x-y$ is also a factor of $x^2-y^2$).

Comment: @ReneSchipperus It doesn't matter. In Cambridge English it is "factorize" which is used in the entire subcontinent India Pak, Bangladesh. In US an other parts it is "factor"

Comment: @imranfat Well you may be owed an apology. If is in the Oxford English Dictionary, it is correct. Ill have to look it up... But is does sound strange to me.

Comment: @imranfat Yes, you do recieve a 100% apology, I havent go the OED here but I have found factorize in Murray's "new" dictionary (from 1901). So factorize is the verb.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus. It's not recieve, but receive...LOL, geeft niet...

Comment: @imranfat Now you are just getting nasty.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-y^2-x+y=(x^2-y^2)-(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y)-(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y-1)$$

Answer (score 2):

If you have already $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$, then
$$
x^2-y^2-(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y)-(x-y)=(x-y)(x+y-1).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Another method to factor $${ x }^{ 2 }-x+\frac { 1 }{ 4 } -{ y }^{ 2 }+y-\frac { 1 }{ 4 } ={ \left( x-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-{ \left( y-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=\left( x-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +y-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \left( x-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } -y+\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) =\left( x-y \right) \left( x+y-1 \right) $$

Comment: what is this method called ? :)

Comment: it hasn't got name)

Answer (score 1):

This is a far less elegant method than the other answers but I'll keep it up for posterity: set it up as a quadratic in $x$.

$$x^2-x+(y-y^2)=0$$
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4(y^2-y)}}{2}$$
$$\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(y^2-y)}}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4(y^2-y)}}{2}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(2x-1+\sqrt{(2y-1)^2}\right)\left(2x-1-\sqrt{(2y-1)^2}\right)$$
$$\left(x+y-1\right)\left(x-y\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice here,

$$x^2 - y^2 - x + y$$
$$(x+y)(x-y)-1(x-y)$$
$$(x-y) (x+y-1)$$
That's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe that $-x+y = -(x-y)$. So both $x^2-y^2$ and $-x+y$ have $x-y$ as a factor. You can use these info to get below factorization

$$
x^2 + y^2 - x +y = (x+y)(x-y)-(x-y) = (x+y-1)(x-y)
$$